# Can I temporarily use normal resistor in place of fusible resistor

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply

I have SMPS that uses 10 ohm 1W fusible resistor. I have located a fusible resistor in Amazon and its gonna take a while to deliver.

I would like to know if I can temporarily use 10 ohm resistor for now in its place or is it too much of a stretch?

Comment: Is the resistor broken? If it is, it acted as a fuse as some other part of the circuit had a fault or is broken. If you have not removed the fault or fixed the circuit, can you guess what happens to the new resistor? If it is not fusible, it won't act fast and it can burn.

Comment: @Justme yes the resistor is broken. Perhaps, IC failure that caused it. Im replacing the IC as it has already arrived.

Comment: Search "slow blow fuse" and "fast blow fuse". For obvious reasons, one cannot be replaced with the other. If your resistor is not of the same variety, complement it (in series) with an appropriate fuse.

Comment: @mkeith sure i understand that having a fuse to prevent damage is cruicial to the application of SMPS. But say if I want to temporarily test the power supply to see if the IC i replaced is working properly, can in that instance I soder ordinary 10ohm resistor instead of fusible resistor?

Comment: A fuse is a safety feature, to protect the rest of the circuit, the environment around it (as in, trying to prevent you to set your house or office on fire) and yourself. Attempting to run a circuit without that protection is most definitely not a good idea, especially when the previous fuse blew up, showing that there is a problem with the circuit.

Comment: @jcaron yes, i think i should wait for the fusible resistor because in case if my diagnosis is wrong (something else may be leaking current or faulty other then the IC) and having a normal resistor may not break the circuit (if thats the case) resulting in more potential damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fusable resistor differs from a normal resistor in that the fusing characteristics are specified and civilised .On high energy stuff like your single phase mains or forklift batteries random resistors can do bad things like Explode or go on fire and not self extinglush or release foul gas .Remember that you are poking Kw into your 1 watt resistor if there is a short in your SMPS . Unless you know what you are doing stick to the correct part .It may blow open circuit if your SMPS is faulty .

Answer (score 0):

Real engineers do things like this all the time. The key is to ask yourself what could go wrong, and what would be the consequences? Then you ask yourself what can you do to make sure the worst consequences don't take place? If it seems like I am equivocating that is because I don't know you and what experiences you have had.

Every time you energize a device that is in some way questionable, you should be prepared to observe it for some time until you are sure it is working properly. Also, and this is really important:

**You have to be able to de-energize the device without risking injury yourself**.

This does not have to be complicated. It can just be the simple precaution of powering the device from an outlet that is accessible and distant from the device. Or, it could be a switched outlet, where the switch is safely distant.

**Also, you need to make sure that you have a safe exit path if it catches on fire.**

So if it should start to smoke extensively or burn, you first de-energize the device, then you flee the room and wait to go back in until the smoke has cleared (if necessary). It may also be a good idea to have a fire extinguisher handy so you can put out a fire if needed.

**Finally, do not leave the energized device unattended.**

Eventually you may come to the conclusion that it is working properly and maybe then you will feel safe to leave it energized unattended. But don't become distracted before that happens and leave it. Always de-energize the device if you have to walk away.

So, you plug it in, and if things go badly, you just unplug it and walk out of the room. Or switch off a breaker and walk out. If it goes really badly and the device ignites a more general fire, then you could use a fire extinguisher (after de-energizing the device).

An example of a bad idea would be plugging it in in such a way that you have to lean over the device to reach the plug. In this case, if it should catch on fire, you will have to lean over it to unplug it. Don't do that!

Another example of poor practice would be working around highly flammable materials. If there are flammable solvents around (Isopropyl alcohol? Acetone?), well, you probably should not energize questionable devices then. Curtains hanging down over the device? Move the device somewhere else, or move the curtains out of the way.

To me, these things are common sense. I hesitate to recommend to a stranger on the internet that they energize a questionable device because I don't know if these things are common sense to other people. Also, none of these precautions need to be elaborate. It is just basic stuff.

I am not trying to talk you out of doing it. It seems like a reasonable thing to do. But reasonable for me may not be the same as reasonable for you.